# How to avoid overflow in calculation matrix determinant with large elements

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, overflow

I am going to calculate the determinant of a random 2D-matrix (G) in Python. The matrix is of size about 30 by 30, where each element is chosen randomly from a large prime field with characteristic P using `random.randrange(0,P)` (e.g. `P= 2^160 - 47`). The problem is that when I use det command of both scipy and numpy they return `inf`. After finding determinant, I want to find the answer in the prime field, that is  `det(G)% P`.

Is there any way to calculate this? Thank you in advance.

Here is a sample code:

```
import numpy as np
import random
from scipy.linalg import det
N= 30
p = 2**160 - 47
G = np.zeros((N, N))
    
for i in range(N):
   for j in range(N):
      G[i][j] = random.randrange(0, p)

ans = det(G)%p
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NumPy is not the right tool for this.  You need a library that can handle arbitrarily large integers.  One option is [SymPy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/index.html).  SymPy even has the function [`randMatrix`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/matrices/matrices.html#sympy.matrices.dense.randMatrix) that can generate your random matrix. For example,

```
import random
from sympy import randMatrix


N = 30
p = 2**160 - 47

G = randMatrix(N, min=0, max=p-1)

ans = G.det() % p
print(ans)
```

A typical run prints

```
381271413373650154061019607002336594108159531272
```

In the call of `randMatrix`, I used `max=p-1`, because the docstring for `randMatrix` implies that the function `random.Random.randint` will be used to generate the random entries in the matrix, and that function includes `max` in the possible random values.  `randrange` does not include `max`.